# I was surprised to read the following about React. Is this still relevant today?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I read the following recently.

> React is MAINLY THE VIEW LAYER.
>
> React is mentioned in the same breath as other Javascript frameworks,
> but "React vs Angular" doesn't make sense because they aren't directly
> comparable. Angular is a complete framework (including a view layer),
> React is not. This is why React is confusing to understand, it's
> emerging in an ecosystem of complete frameworks, but it's mostly the
> view.
>
> ...
>
> **You can't build a fully functional dynamic application with React
> alone**. We'll learn more about why below.

In particular, I was really surprised by the last statement, "You can't build a fully functional dynamic application with React alone". Following on from that, the article went on to say this.

> Don't forget that React is mostly the view.
>
> 1. You DON'T GET any of the following:
>
> - An event system (other than vanilla DOM events)
> - Any AJAX capabilities whatsoever
> - Any form of a data layer
> - Promises
> - **Any application framework**
>
> React on its own **not enough for most real world use cases**.

What!? So, in other words, you would use something like Angular or Vue along with React!? Or is this just outdated content?

Comment: `is this just an outdated article?` - link?

Comment: @JaromandaX https://blog.andrewray.me/reactjs-for-stupid-people/

Comment: *it was written in 2014, and the React ecosystem has changed since then*

Comment: But i also would say if you really plan to create a maintainable application you should choose some other framework than react

Comment: @GalAbra sure, but the title on reactjs.org is litteralt "A JavaScript library for building user interfaces" - which the article emphesises.

Comment: @GalAbra So, just to get my confidence back... Now, React IS enough for real world use cases. Correct?

Comment: The article is very outdated though not entirely incorrect. I'd argue you don't need any event system other than what DOM offers at all), "AJAX capabilities" these days means `fetch` which is supported by all modern browsers, "any form of a data layer" = react props and state, which these days include reducers too, promises are a language feature, modern browsers and transpilers are needed (so this one is a mistake in the article). You'd have to define "real world use cases" to get an answer though. I can give you plenty for which React was enough back then too.

Comment: Cool. Thank you so much to all of you. I can safely presume that React IS enough for real world applications. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> So, in other words, you would use something like Angular or Vue along with React!?

No. Angular for instance comes with things like Ajax helper functions built-in, but it also has its own View layer. If you were using Angular then you wouldn't use React because it has its own equivalent.

React does one thing and it does it well. If you need to do something React doesn't do (and you will) then you need to either use the raw browser features (if applicable), write your own code to do it or use another library.

Vanilla DOM events are just fine for many cases. You can throw the RxJS library in if you need more complex event handling.

Keeping your state in some local JS objects is fine for many cases. You can throw Redux or similar in if you want more powerful state management.

`fetch` is just fine for many cases. Etc.

Comment: I appreciate the answer Quentin. You mentioned "or use another library". So, I would be interested in knowing what library are you talking about? In particular, what application framework would you use along with this view-based library? So in other words, what library would you use to cover the M and C, if React does the V?

Comment: I gave examples in the following paragraphs.

Comment: Okay, so you would use bits and bobs to do various things. But is it common to use another complete application framework, along with React to handle the view?

Comment: I'm not aware of anybody writing a monolithic "does everything" framework that *doesn't* have a built-in view layer.

Comment: No, sure. I understand that too. However, it appears that React handles the view, better than many other libraries. So, I would like to know if it is common for people to use another "complete" application framework, but just substitute the native view handling with React instead.

Comment: If you are using React you will use it for view based applications (and maybe a strong backend) As you already guessed its not best suited for fat-client applications, but its possible to use together with RxJS, Redux, Backbone etc. So it can get to a full application instead of just rendering views. But if you already got theoretical issues with that, you probably should use Vue or Angular as they ship with everything you may ever need. (I would recommend vue as it is also lightweight but got many plugins which are exactly ment for vue)